# How do you compare NSFontSymbolicTraits and NSFontBoldTrait in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift, nsfont

I'm trying to bitwise compare [`NSFontSymbolicTraits`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFontDescriptor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSFontSymbolicTraits) and `NSFontBoldTrait` *in Swift*.

In Objective-C it'd be done like this:

```
BOOL isBold = (fontDescriptorSymbolicTraits & UIFontDescriptorTraitBold);
```

So I'm thinking it should be this in Swift:

```
let isBold:Bool = font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits & NSFontBoldTrait
```

...However that results in the following error:

> Cannot invoke '&' with an argument list of type '(NSFontSymbolicTraits, Int)'

Anyone know what I'm missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Notes**:

- I've Googled like a madman and spend hours trying to find a solution and read through the documentation for [`NSFontDescriptor`](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFontDescriptor_Class/index.html) and the other [`NSFont`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFont_Class/index.html)-related classes.
- I don't know Obj-C very well so I don't know if it's because the [`NSFont*Trait` constants are implemented differently in Swift](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFontDescriptor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Typeface_Information)? Not even sure if that's the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Swift, `NSFontSymbolicTraits` is a type alias for `UInt32`. So to check for the existence of a particular trait, you need to compare the result of your bitwise `&` to zero. Unfortunately, the individual constraints have been imported as type `Int`, so you also need to convert them to the right type:

```
let isBold = 0 != (font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits & NSFontSymbolicTraits(NSFontBoldTrait))
```

If you wanted to do this in iOS (instead of OS X), `UIFont` has a different implementation. `UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits` is a `RawOptionSetType`, so you compare the result of your `&` with `nil`:

```
let isBold = nil != (font.fontDescriptor().symbolicTraits & UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits.TraitBold)
```

Comment: @matt Huh? `var fontDescriptor: NSFontDescriptor! { get }`

Comment: `let font = NSFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12); 
println(font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits & NSFontSymbolicTraits(NSFontBoldTrait))` prints `0`.

Comment: Well, okay, but it sure is different in iOS. You'd think they'd iron this sort of difference out.

Comment: In iOS 8 it's like this: `let isBold = 0 != (font.fontDescriptor().symbolicTraits.toRaw() & (UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits.TraitBold).toRaw())`

Comment: @matt: See update, you don't need to get the raw values.

Comment: In my tests, I did. I got a compiler error otherwise.

Comment: @NateCook: Thanks. Works like a charm. Nice touch to include the iOS version too.

Answer (score 0):

Update based on Nates answer, since his iOS version doesn't work for me. Which most likely is due to the changes in swift since 2014.

iOS, Swift 4(.2):

```
extension UIFontDescriptor {
    var isBold: Bool {
        if 0 == (symbolicTraits.rawValue & UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits.traitBold.rawValue) {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5.4 on iOS.

```
let isBold = font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitBold)
```